# How to get state restoration to restore all windows/tabs on macOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I have a non-document based macOS AppKit app. It has one window instantiated automatically by the storyboard. I have sub-classed `NSWindowController` and added a `override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?)` to enable the + button on the tab-bar. My main view controller lets the user rename the tab title and the window title is set to the same. This is kind of like how Xcode tab renaming works.

Additionally I have sub-classed `NSWindow` and added a `restorableStateKeyPaths` to ensure tab and window titles are automatically restored on app restart.

This all works great.

But only for the first tab. The main window is loaded and it has the tab and window titles set automatically.

The other tabs (windows) are not restored.

Any hints on what I miss to make all tabs restored?

My `NSWindowController`:

```
class MyWindowController: NSWindowController {
    var subview: MyWindowController?

    @IBAction override func newWindowForTab(_ sender: Any?) {
        let story = self.storyboard
        let windowVC = story?.instantiateInitialController() as! Self

        window?.addTabbedWindow(windowVC.window!, ordered: .above)
        subview = windowVC

        windowVC.window?.orderFront(self.window)
        windowVC.window?.makeKey()
    }
}
```

My `NSWindow`:

```
class MyWindow: NSWindow {
    override class var restorableStateKeyPaths: [String] {
       return [ "self.tab.title", "self.title" ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make sure that state restoration is enabled for your user, you can do this by going to Preferences->General and unchecking "Close windows when quitting an app".

Then you should use a restoration class in order to restore all open windows.

Basically if an NSWindow doesn't have a restoration class it won't be preserved across launches, that includes your storyboard loaded window. In this case what is happening is Cocoa is ignoring all window preservation because you haven't defined a restoration class for any of your windows so it resorts to its default behavior which is loading the initial storyboard controller.

Implementing restoration class is easy, just create a restoration class that inherits from NSObject and conforms to NSWindowRestoration, then implement its only required type method `restoreWindow(identifier:state:completionHandler)` like so:

```
class MyAppWindowRestoration: NSObject, NSWindowRestoration {
    
    static func restoreWindow(withIdentifier identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier,
                              state: NSCoder,
                              completionHandler: @escaping (NSWindow?, Error?) -> Void) {
        // 1.- Retrieve and show the window
        // Retrieve a new instance of the only window
        let window = (NSStoryboard.main?.instantiateInitialController() as? NSWindowController)?.window
        
        // Call the completion handler with the window and no errors
        completionHandler(window, nil)
    }

}
```

Then just assign this class as the window restoration class on every window you want restored, you can do this everywhere after the window has loaded:

```
window.restorationClass = MyAppWindowRestoration.self
```

Unfortunately Apple's documentation on state restoration completely sucks so if you have any more questions let me know ;)

Comment: Hi Gilberto. First of, thanks for your answer. However, I'm struggling to get this to work in my app with my tabs. Could you provide a complete demo app or more specifically describe where to place the code above?

Comment: Also, if you want to support window restoration regardless of the System Prefs setting, you can set @"NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows" = @YES in your userDefaults (needs to be explicit, not as a default, to work).